# How to create simple coffescript example without rails

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I am new to coffeescript. I saw a coffeescript video in Rails casts.com. From that episode I understand how to convert the normal Js and Jquery to coffeescript code and the usage of coffeescript.

I am trying to create a coffeescript example without rails. I wetn through the coffeescript site. They first install Node.js. I tried to install node.js in windows and ubuntu, but I had failures. I followed the instruction as per this site:

http://howtonode.org/how-to-install-nodejs#ubuntu

For ubuntu I got "bash: ./configure?: No such file or directory" error when I execute the following command

```
./configure
```

Can anyone help me to create simple coffescript example without rails?

One more thing - In Mac "By the help of homebrew I can see the compiled js of coffescript code through compiled and Display Js window".  Are there any options available in windows and ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would bet the easiest way to install Node.js on Ubuntu is through APT:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

It probably will get some outdated version but it can be enough for some tests.

If you prefer the latest version (which is a reasonable preference), I bet it would be easier to install Node.js from the dist package. Just copy and paste this on terminal:

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.5.0.tar.gz && \
tar zvxf node-v0.5.0.tar.gz && \
cd node-v0.5.0 && \
./configure && \
make && \
sudo make install
```

This line will:

- download the latest Node.js source code with `wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.5.0.tar.gz`
- uncompress the downloaded source code with `tar zvxf node-v0.5.0.tar.gz`
- enter into the source code with `cd node-v0.5.0`
- set the build parameters with `./configure`
- effectively build the Node.js executable with `make`
- install the built Node.js in your path with `sudo make install`

The `&&` means "execute the next command if the previous command succeeds" (for example `wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.5.0.tar.gz && tar zvxf node-v0.5.0.tar.gz` means that we will download the package with `wget` and *iff the download succeeds* we will unpack the download file with `tar`. The backslashes (`\`) are here for allowing us to break all the series of commands in more than one line because, by default, we would have a big line:

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.5.0.tar.gz && tar zvxf node-v0.5.0.tar.gz && cd node-v0.5.0 && ./configure && make &&  sudo make install
```

Then, you can install `npm` with this simple command, found in the own [`npm` github page](https://github.com/isaacs/npm):

```
$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

With `npm`, it will be *too* easy to install coffee, as you can see in the [CoffeeScript page](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/):

```
$ npm install coffee-script
```

Now, just run your tests:

```
$ coffee
coffee> a = key: 'value'
{ key: 'value' }
coffee> a.key
'value'
```

Does it look like to much work? You can try CoffeeScript in the [language page](http://jashkenas.github.com). Just click in "Try CoffeeScript" and a console will appear to you.

Answer (score 1):

For testing and demo purposes it may be sufficient to have your CoffeeScript compiled directly in browser. You can include the CoffeeScript compiler and your code in a  tag.

This method is not efficient though so please use it for playing around.

Please see this section on how to set things up:

["text/coffeescript" Script Tags](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#scripts)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu 11.10 has an up-to-date package for CoffeeScript](http://oylenshpeegul.typepad.com/blog/2011/10/coffeescript-in-ubuntu-1110.html).

```
sudo apt-get install coffeescript
```